# Why only last item is saved in database?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have problem, becouse only last item from loop is saved in database.
Im using CakePhp 2.x

Controller:

```
for ($x=1; $x <= count($this->request->data['Goodsandoffer'])/3;$x++){
                            $promID = $this->request->data['Goodsandoffer']['promotionaloffer_id_'.$x];
                            if($this->request->data['Goodsandoffer']['cenaPromocyjna_'.$x] != ''){
                                $helperReqestTable3 = array('promotionaloffer_id'=>$this->request->data['Goodsandoffer']['promotionaloffer_id_'.$x],'good_id'=>$this->request->data['Goodsandoffer']['good_id_'.$x],'cenaPromocyjna'=>$this->request->data['Goodsandoffer']['cenaPromocyjna_'.$x]);
                                $helperReqestTable['Goodsandoffer']=$helperReqestTable3;
                                debug($helperReqestTable);
                                $this->Goodsandoffer->save($helperReqestTable);
                            }
                        }
```

Here is how look my debug in loop:

```
array(
    'Goodsandoffer' => array(
        'promotionaloffer_id' => '7',
        'good_id' => '18',
        'cenaPromocyjna' => '1'
    )
)
```

And in next interation:

```
array(
    'Goodsandoffer' => array(
        'promotionaloffer_id' => '7',
        'good_id' => '19',
        'cenaPromocyjna' => '2'
    )
)
```

In database is created only one row with last item.

Model:

```
class Goodsandoffer extends AppModel {

    public $displayField = 'id';

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Promotionaloffer' => array(
            'className' => 'Promotionaloffer',
            'foreignKey' => 'promotionaloffer_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'Good' => array(
            'className' => 'Good',
            'foreignKey' => 'good_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Oh...U have right. I do this but before loop. Thx man. Write this in answer I will give u point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried calling `$this->Goodsandoffer->create()` before you call save? That way you're *definitely* telling Cake to create a new record each time.

The general process of creating and saving data in Cake is:

1. `$this->Model->create()`
2. `$this->Model->set($data_array)`
3. `$this->Model->save()`

You can also eliminate step 2 above by passing you `$data_array` to the `save()` function:

```
$this->Model->create();
$this->Model->save($data_array);
```

**NOTE:** [from the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array) (if you aren't using `create()`):

> When calling save in a loop, don’t forget to call clear().

Another way you could create new data would be to make sure the primary key for your model is `null` in the data set you pass into save, although this is a little less obvious and probably best to stick to the create/[set/]save flow:

```
$data = array('id' => null, 'somefield' => 'foobar');
$this->Model->save($data); // new record created
```

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp 2.0 $this->Model->create() create work fine. But if you are using cakephp version 3 or greater then 3. Then follow the below code

```
$saveData['itemId']             = 1;

$saveData['qty']                = 2;

$saveData['type']               = '0';

$saveData['status']             = 'active';

$saveData = $this->Model->newEntity($saveData);

$this->Model->save($materialmismatch);
```

**In normal case we use patchEntity**

```
$this->Model->patchEntity($saveData, $this->request->data);
```

It will only save last values of array so you have to use newEntity() with data